# What is the default color of the label and postFix in TextField

Tags: flutter

How to select the color of the 'Email' and 'Email Icon' in unfocused state of that text field.

to choose their color I set the primaryColor(for focused state), what is the value (or field in the theme) that's responsible for changing their color in the unfocused state

[image]

[image]

```
Theme(
                  data: ThemeData(
                      primaryColor: Colors.red,
                      ),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            style: BorderStyle.solid,
                            color: Colors.indigo[500],
                          )),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                      ),
                      labelText: 'E-Mail',
                      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.mail),
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            style: BorderStyle.solid,
                            color: Colors.cyan,
                          )),
                    ),
                    cursorColor: Colors.white,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 1):

For the label's color : `labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, color: HERE),`

For the icon's color : `prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.mail, color: HERE),`